# check the load of an application with synthetic users

Tags: node.js, performance, testing, load

I am looking to find out the response times that takes for my nodejs application with (lets say) when 1000 users uses it simultaneously. I believe this is called stress testing. How Can I acheive this ?

I am new to testing area and yet to acquire knowledge on tools that will be used.

Edit: I need to know how to have virtual users for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand the response times for an application under load, you need two components:

1. A load driver

   There's a number of available tools that will simulate users making HTTP requests. A simple open source option is ([Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). The following page in the documentation shows you how to create a web test plan, including adding virtual users:
   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html
2. A performance monitoring tool

   In order to understand how your application is performing under the load, and measure application responsiveness, you need a performance monitoring tool. One set of options is to track the performance of 'http' monitoring events using [Node Application Metrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics), either using the API directly, or using an open source monitoring stack like Elasticsearch/Kibana using the [ELK Connector for Node Application Metrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics-elk). There's a getting started guide to monitoring Node.js application performance with Elasticsearch/Kibana here:
   https://developer.ibm.com/open/2015/09/07/using-elasticsearch-and-kibana-with-node-application-metrics/

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I am looking for.